# How can I verify the z values of my countour line file in ArcGIS/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, elevation, z-value

I have a shapefile with countour lines  and I want to verify if the z value for each countourline  is correct when compared with their neighbors.

How can I do that in ArcGIS or QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Cátia! Perhaps this post might help: [Checking if z values of contour lines are correct using ArcGIS Desktop?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7773/checking-if-z-values-of-contour-lines-are-correct-using-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Please decide which of the two desktop GIS products you wish to ask about in this question.